# how to include third party gems like 'spree' in Vendor folder 

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, spree

I am using gem 'spree'. when i install it, it gets installed inside the particular bundler. (I am using rvm).

Problem:
I want to modify the gem according to my needs, so its better if its located inside the Vendor folder of my current project.

Should i do something like copy paste?

Comment: Could you explain how you would like to modify this gem? Why not just follow the Logic Customization guide? http://guides.spreecommerce.com/logic_customization.html

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I'll follow the guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by giving the path to the gem.

It would be something like this  `gem 'spree' -> /vendor/`